# Redux assign elements to nested object in state giving its key

Tags: reactjs, redux

giving a state tree that looks like this:

```
machines:{
    "first_machine" : {},
    "second_machine" : {options:[], packages[]},
}
```

How can I assign "options" and "packages" to a given "machine name" in the Reducer (all machine names exist in the state tree, I just need to access to the one that its key matches the payload.machineName and assign to it)?
This is the action creator:

```
export const submitconfigMachine = (machineName, options, packages) =>({
    type: CONFIG_MACHINE,
    payload: {machineName, options, packages}
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your reducer currently look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { machineName, ...data } = action.payload;
return {
  ...state,
  machines: {
    ...state.machines,
    [machineName]: data,
  },
};
```